# SQL server 2016 SP1 CU4 issues, upgraded from SQL Server 2016 RTM CU1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Mirrored Servers (primary and secondary) running fine on SQL Server 2016 RTM CU1.. After the upgrade to SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU4 both servers OS became unresponsive after 23-25 hours, bizarrely SQL Server is still running.

Nothing writes to event log when windows becomes unresponsive. The only odd thing I can see are the log backups which run every 30 mins which stop just before this happens and don't resume. However diff and full continue. Also spotted a couple times a long running query after/during log backup.

```
Process Full Command: (@P1 nchar(86))RESTORE LABELONLY FROM DISK=@P1
```

Has anyone seen this issue with SP1 CU4? If so any fix?

> ```
> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU4) (KB4024305) - 13.0.4446.0 (X64)   
> Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
> ```

Comment: Could it be related to version 13 of the ODBC driver? spotted some people had issues and a fix came out with 13.1

Comment: How are you currently resolving the issue?  What, exactly, is listed in your *System **and** Application Windows Logs* just prior to the issues?

Comment: Ended up reverting both CU4 and SP1. There is absolutely nothing in the Windows system and application logs.

Comment: [This bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3139829/update-from-sql-server-2016-sp1-cu3-to-sp1-cu4-fails-update-process-freezes) is the only SP1 CU4 reference I'm finding on connect at the moment, but the comment from the MS rep makes me wonder if they pushed out a buggy patch.  You should submit a connect item regardless, but hopefully someone has run into similar issues and can provide better assistance.

Comment: Ah interesting potentially that could be related i have raised a connect item https://partnersupport.microsoft.com/en-us/par_servplat/forum/par_sqlserv/sql-server-2016-sp1-cu4-issues-upgraded-from-sql/e0c57a04-9e19-44da-85a6-6a048e9974b5?tm=1505816251897